# Init parent class with a Child contstructor in Java, theory

Tags: java, theory, classcastexception

I've just tested this code.

**Main.**

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent parent = new Child(12, "Lorem", 12);
        if (parent instanceof Parent) {
            System.out.println("Parent");
        } else if (parent instanceof Child) {
            System.out.println("Child");
        }
        outChild(parent);
    }

    private static void outChild(Parent parent) {
        Child child = (Child) parent;
        System.out.print(child);
    }
}
```

**Parent.**

```
public class Parent {

    int id;
    String name;

    public Parent(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**Child.**

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    int extra;

    public Child(int id, String name, int extra) {
        super(id, name);
        this.extra = extra;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id: " + id + ", name: " + name + ", extra: " + extra;
    }

}
```

I need some theory. Why is my `parent` instance considered a `Parent` class instance but has `extra` field declared in `Child` only?

If I had written `Parent parent = new Parent(12, "Lorem");` and called `outChild(Parent parent)`, I would have gotten a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: You don't have a `Parent` instance, because `new Child(12, "Lorem", 12)` creates a `Child` instance. Every `Child` _is_ an `Object`,  `Parent` and `Child`, and every `Parent` _is_ a `Object` and  `Parent`.

Comment: parent IS a Parent AND a Child. In other words `if (parent instanceof Child)` is true too but never tested.

Comment: you simply can not cast an instance of `Parent` to `Child` because it is not derived from `Child`... obviously

Comment: When trying to learn polymorphism, it is usually not helpful to call classes `Parent` and `Child`. The everyday meaning of these words is that the `Parent` **has** a `Child`. However, that is not the case in this example. In this example, the `Child` **is** a `Parent`. If you're not fully comfortable with the concepts of polymorphism, I would suggest that you rename the `Parent` class to `Animal` and rename the `Child` class to `Cat`. Then you'd have a `Cat` which **is** an `Animal` instead of a `Child` which **is** a `Parent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Parent parent` is a reference, not an object.  This means you have a reference to something which is a Parent as a minimum, but could be a sub class.